# エクセルで1つのセルの中に異なる色付きで入力された文字列を自動で分割して新しいセルに代入したい

Tags: vba, excel

エクセルで1つのセルの中に異なる色付きで入力された文字列を自動で分割してセルに代入するにはどのようにしたらいいでしょうか。

たとえば
セル[A1] あああ（黒色）いいい（青色）ううう（黒色）

とセルに入力されているものを

セル[A2] あああ（黒色）
セル[A3] いいい（青色）
セル[A4] ううう（黒色）

と分割したいという具合です。

Answer (score 1):

[Range.Charactersプロパティ](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters)で1文字ずつフォントを取得できますので、素直にループしながら判定することで目的を達成できます。

**サンプルコード**

```
Sub ボタン1_Click()
    Dim cell As range
    Set cell = range("A1")
    Dim color As Integer '現在のカラーインデックス
    Dim row As Integer   '現在の出力先行番号
    Dim start As Integer '現在の色の開始位置
    color = cell.Characters(start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex '先頭の色
    row = 2
    start = 1
    
    For i = 1 To cell.Characters.Count
        Dim ch As Characters
        Dim c As Integer
        '1文字ずつ文字色をチェック
        Set ch = cell.Characters(start:=i, Length:=1)
        c = ch.Font.ColorIndex
        If c <> color Then
            '直前の文字列と現在の文字列が違う場合は直前の文字列まで出力
            Cells(row, 1).Value = cell.Characters(start, i - start).Text
            Cells(row, 1).Font.ColorIndex = color
            '現在の文字列で変数を更新
            start = i
            row = row + 1
            color = c
        End If
    Next
    '末尾の文字列まで出力
    Cells(row, 1).Value = cell.Characters(start, i - start).Text
    Cells(row, 1).Font.ColorIndex = color
End Sub
```